Некорректно отображается сайт после загрузки его на хостинг
Мой первый опыт загрузки на хостинг.
Когда смотришь сайт с пк, все отображается так, как ожидалось. (Использовал toggle device toolbar для проверки адаптивности, браузеры - яндекс, гугл, опера, операJX)
Когда открыл с телефона, адаптивность вышла погулять (часть отображается, часть не отображается)
Скриншоты с ПК и телефона.
http://www.carspadeteiling.ru/ - ссылка на сайт. (там небезопасное соединение, я знаю, пока не разбирался с этим)
https://post-images.org/gallery.php?photo=4kSF3i - ссылка на скрины (которые чачинаются с названия "Скриншот" - это ПК в режиме разработки расширения телефона, остальные ,это скрины с телефона

Ну как минимум у вас девять битых ссылок на картинки, и это прекрасно воспроизводится на ПК банальным увеличением масштаба

https://postimg.cc/Z02rqndS - появились ошибки. (Сначала, просто, не показывало этих ошибок, а спустя, получается полтора часа, вот)
Я как понимаю + выше написали, это ошибка в путях на картинки, если починить, то все будет в порядке, верно мыслю?
